# R CMD install : clean libs before a new installation

Tags: r, package

If there is any option I can set to `R CMD INSTALL` to remove all installed libs ( under package installation directory) before a new installation?

I tried

```
R CMD install -c --preclean
```

But it does not work. Should I create a clean config?

PS : I am under windows.

*EDIT* more context:

I am developing a package. I generate the lib automatically at each build. So I need to remove the old ones each time I have a modification.  Removing the entire library is Ok for me also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is old, but I just ran into this myself. I am assuming here by "installed libs" you mean libraries internal to your package on which your package depends. (In my case, it is libzip and libzippp that I am cleaning up.)

My solution was here: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Configure-and-cleanup

> Under a Unix-alike only, an executable (Bourne shell) script *cleanup* is  executed as the last thing by R CMD INSTALL if option --clean was given, and by R CMD build when preparing the package for building from its source.

I created a file named "cleanup" that is a Bash script and change directories, call make distclean and remove so and o files there. This is called at the beginning and the end of the build/install process. The cleanup script is called from within the package directory.